# Scrolling of images using UIScrollView in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am a newbie to iphone development and i am doing a simple app for practice. In that app,there is only one view that has an image on it. I want to be able to swipe left or right and have the first image go out of the view and the second image to come in. The images are different and I want it to look like they are connected. I need it to be able to change the image or restart after a series of swipes. I am doing this using ScrollView only.

I have tried something:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *imgView;
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

//- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page;
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize imgView,scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
/*
- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil])
    {
        pageNumber = page;
    }
    return self;
}
*/



- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollview
{
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollview.bounds.size.width, 0);
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender
{

    NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1.jpeg",@"2.jpeg",@"3.jpeg", nil];
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    CGRect cRect = scrollView.bounds;

    for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++){
        imgView = [images objectAtIndex:i];
        imgView.frame = cRect;
        [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
        cRect.origin.x += cRect.size.width;
    }

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * images.count, scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);

}

@end
```

When i run the app, I am still not able to swipe across the images. Am i doing something wrong? Need some guidance on this. Thanks..

Comment: What changes did you do to the XIB file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that you have a connection in Interface Builder with an `IBOutlet` that does not exist in your view controller class.

Make sure your IBOutlets are named correctly and that you have removed all obsolete connections in IB.

Comment: done that.. but i still can't swipe through the images. Am i still doing some mistakes?

Comment: But it fixed the crash right? "Can't swipe through the images" is too vague to give any help. Maybe you should accept this answer and start a new question.

Comment: can u do me a favour? just have a look at my code and see any errors i am doing?

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing in changePage. Why allocate new scroll views? Why reinitiate your images array? You should do all this once in `viewDidLoad`, i.e. lay out your images in your scroll view. Set `pagingEnabled` of your scroll view to `YES` and it should just work automatically, with or without UIPageControl.

Comment: how do you ay out your images in your scroll view? where should scrollView.pageEnabled = YES; go? in the changePage?

Answer (score 0):

scrollView.ContentSize = (scrollView.frame.size.width * images.count

,scrollView.frame.size.height)

do this after lopping it will swipe

Comment: After the loop  for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++){
        imgView = [images objectAtIndex:i];
        imgView.frame = cRect;
        [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
        cRect.origin.x += cRect.size.width;
    }

Comment: still can't... what should i do?

Comment: remove the content off set line from the code it is not necessary..and accept my ans if it happens thank u

Comment: no didn't work.. i am not able to connect my changePage function to any scroll view...

Comment: means call is not going on changePagefunction.